# Mercurial ACL Groups causing 502 error

Tags: permissions, mercurial, acl

am setting up my mercurial repo using the ACL extension. When I configure the ACL.deny section I am trying to deny a specific group of users. When blocking them individually ACL works as intended and aborts their change sets. However, when trying to add all these users to one group, and then block the group Mercurial gives a 502 Bad Gateway error.

When looking through my IIS logs I get no meaningful error message, and at this point am basically stuck. Does anyone have experience with this, or have an idea on what could be causing this?

Does the 502 error and the setting up of groups have anything in common, or is that misconfiguration of our IIS or SSL? I have looked and have seen no versions of this problem before, so I am thinking it is not a mercurial issue, but am asking for help with diagnostics.